# Quote mark automatically generated during mysql import

Tags: mysql, import, load, quote

This is my .csv file created using libreoffice, all in the first column

```
1,John,BE12,QQE
2,Bob,ZD61,XYZ
3,EDDY,ZA43,TRS
4,Merry,ZA43,MXY
```

This my tables structure in mysql :
    id,name,code1,code2

I run this to import .csv to mysql :
    mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/customers.csv' INTO TABLE Cars FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

Everything went well, except the code2 field has quote mark (") at the end of the value. So they look like this :

```
id  name   code1  code2

1   John   BE12   QQE"
2   Bob    ZD61   XYZ"
3   EDDY   ZA43   TRS"
4   Merry  ZA43   MXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

When saving the .csv for the first time, a dialog box will ask whether or not to include " (quote mark) as the text delimiter. The answer should be NO, otherwise it will end up having " (quote mark) at the end of the field.